# Loop until answer is a string

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm trying to loop this question until the user's input is a string value:

> **Question: What is your name?**
>
> - I don't want the user to just press enter and leave the name blank.
> - I don't want the user's input to be numeric/numbers.

Please see my code below:

```
name1 = gets.chomp.to_s    
loop do
  print "Please enter your name "
  name1 = gets.chomp.to_s
  if name1.empty?
    puts "No input."
  else name1.to_i
    puts "Illegal character ':'"
  end
end
```

With this code, I can't proceed to the next question even if I input a string value. Please help.

Comment: "until the user's input is String value" -- User's input is always a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues:

1. Your input and output is out of order. You gather input before prompting and that input (from your first line) is never used:

   ```
   name1 = gets.chomp.to_s           # <- Ruby is waiting for input
   loop do
     print "Please enter your name " # <- user is prompted to enter name
     name1 = gets.chomp.to_s         # <- previous input is overwritten
     # ...
   end
   ```

   The first line should probably be deleted.
2. [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) might return `nil`, but [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) *always* returns a string. Calling `to_s` afterwards is therefore superfluous.
3. Your `if-else` construct is actually:

   ```
   if name1.empty?
     puts "No input."
   else
     name1.to_i
     puts "Illegal character ':'"
   end
   ```

   So whenever the input is not `empty?`, you convert it to an integer (discarding the result) and print an error message. You probably want an `elsif` instead (`/.../` is a [regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html) and `\d` matches a digit):

   ```
   if name1.empty?
     puts 'No input.'
   elsif name1.match? /\d/
     puts 'Digits not allowed.'
   end
   ```

   You could also use a [`case` expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression):

   ```
   case name1
   when ''
     puts 'No input.'
   when /\d/
     puts 'Digits not allowed.'
   end
   ```
4. You never break out of your `loop`. The code keeps looping even if no error was found. This can be fixed by adding a [`break` statement](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) in an `else` branch (to either `if` or `case`):

   ```
     # ...
   else
     break
   end
   ```

Comment: Looks like the OP also wants to break from the loop. And actually that seems to be the OP's main concern in this question (despite the many other issues that you pointed out). Probably you might want to add an `else` branch.

Answer (score -1):

`gets.chomp` will always return a string, and as such there is no need to call `to_s` on the method.

If you don't want the user to be able to input any integers, you could use the following for a clean solution:

`name.count("0-9") > 0`

If this returns `true`, then you know that the user's input contains at least one number.

Comment: If you want to detect a digit, matching with a regex that has `\d` is enough. You don't need to count.

Comment: That's true, but I thought giving a ruby solution would be easier for OP to understand. Plus, it's more readable.

Comment: Using regex is possible within Ruby, and that is what I meant. Regex match is much more readable than counting how may matches there are, and then seeing that it is positive.

Comment: Slightly late, but I completely disagree. In the solution I gave, even if you're not familiar with Ruby, you can still figure out what's going on. If you're not familiar with regex however, well, you'll have no idea what's it doing.